# Room - How to get COUNT value from DAO query?

Tags: android, android-room, dao

I have a query in my Room DAO that (for the provided `countryId`) queries my `share_groups` table and returns rows which include a `num_twitter_users` figure (which is calculated by counting the number of populated rows in the related `share_group_individuals` table).

This is the code for the query:

```
@Query("SELECT `share_groups`.`_id`, `share_group_name`, `share_group_description`, `share_group_instructions`, `share_group_order`, `share_group_is_visible`, `share_groups`.`last_modified`" +

    // `num_twitter_users` will contain the number of share_group_individuals within this share_group that have a Twitter username.
    ", COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN (`share_group_individuals`.`share_group_individual_twitter` IS NOT NULL AND `share_group_individuals`.`share_group_individual_twitter` != '') THEN `share_group_individuals`.`_id` ELSE NULL END)) AS `num_twitter_users`" +

    " FROM `share_groups`" +

    // Join with `share_group_individuals` - on countryId
    " LEFT JOIN `share_group_individuals` ON (`share_group_individuals`.`share_group_id` = `share_groups`.`_id`" +
    " AND `share_group_individuals`.`share_group_individual_country_id` = :countryId)" +

    // Search on countryId
    " WHERE `share_group_individuals`.`share_group_individual_country_id` = :countryId" +

    " GROUP BY `share_groups`.`share_group_name`, `share_group_individuals`.`share_group_id`" +

    // Only return share_groups that contain at least 1 share_group_individual with a Twitter account
    " HAVING `num_twitter_users` > 0" +

    " ORDER BY `share_group_order` ASC")
LiveData<List<ShareGroup>> getAllShareGroups(long countryId);
```

However, I cannot access the `num_twitter_users` value from the returned `LivaData<List<ShareGroup>>`.

I'm wondering if part of the solution may be to create a `ShareGroupWithData` POJO (and therefore return a `LivaData<List<ShareGroupWithData>>` from my query) but, if this is the correct approach, how would I populate the `numTwitterUsers` variable within the `ShareGroupWithData` class?

I couldn't find any information on this online or in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/package-summary), so a point in the right direction and/or some example code would be much appreciated.

For completeness, my `share_groups` table that is represented by this entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "share_groups")
public class ShareGroup {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_name")
    private String shareGroupName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_description")
    private String shareGroupDescription;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_instructions")
    private String shareGroupInstructions;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_order", defaultValue = "10")
    private int shareGroupOrder;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_is_visible", defaultValue = "1")
    private boolean shareGroupIsVisible;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_modified")
    private long lastModified;

...
}
```

And my `share_groups_individual` table is represented by this entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "share_group_individuals",
        indices = {@Index(name = "index_share_group_id", value = "share_group_id")},
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = ShareGroup.class, parentColumns = "_id", childColumns = "share_group_id", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
)
public class ShareGroupIndividual {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_id")
    private long shareGroupId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_individual_country_id", defaultValue = "-1")
    private long shareGroupIndividualCountryId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_individual_name")
    private String shareGroupIndividualName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "share_group_individual_twitter")
    private String shareGroupIndividualTwitter;

...
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would work if you'll create a separate class for your query result. Something like this:
`data class ResultType(
       @Embedded
       val grup: ShareGroup,
       @Embedded
       val individual: ShareGroupIndividual,
       val num_twitter_users: Int
    )`

Comment: @Daniil Thanks for your help, but I've got it sussed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I solved it by creating a POJO like this:

```
public class ShareGroupWithData {

    @Embedded
    public ShareGroup shareGroup;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "num_twitter_users", defaultValue = "0")
    public int numTwitterUsers;
...
}
```

with my DAO code changing to:

`LiveData<List<ShareGroupWithData>> getAllShareGroupsWithData(long countryId);`